# Ubuntu only boots with advanced recovery options after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 22.04, startup

I have a computer that someone set up for me with two options during boot: Windows or Ubuntu.

All was fine under the Ubuntu system for about 8 months. The other week I was prompted to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 which I did.

Today, I ran the updater and it told me to restart the computer.

Now when I restart and I choose Ubuntu, it won't start and hangs.

I have the option to boot Ubuntu with Advanced options. I have tried all of them.  The first two options, generic and recovery mode, don't work.

But the second generic option starts Ubuntu properly and I arrive at the Ubuntu desktop.

What has happened and what can I do to resolve this so it starts normally without having to use the advanced boot options?

No hardware has changed and the computer is only used for basic word processing and web.

I am a relative newbie and perhaps out my depth with knowing how to resolve issues under Ubuntu.

** NOTE **

THIS IS AN EDIT TO ATTACH SOME SCREENSHOTS.
note: screenshot with text at top only

the first error screenshot existed and ubuntu did continue to start to desktop OK. i UNDERSTAND THAT this could be a bios setting that doesnt affect ubuntu starting.

note: other screenshots showing a list..is what happens now..
it displays this list, then in a moment goes to a blank screen with cursor where it stays for ever.
does anything in this list indicate a problem I could solve?

[image: FIRST ERROR SCREENSHOT (BUT UBUNTU STARTED WITH THIS ERROR OK, SO SEE IMAGE 2 PLEASE]

[image: this list comes up before it goes to a blank screen with cursor and hangs forever]

Comment: Is there any error message when you try to start Ubuntu in the normal way? If so, can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1426830/edit) the question and post a screenshot of the error message (you can shoot a photo with your phone)?

Comment: Well, the first error you did was to upgrade without having a full backup of your system (and not backup with a built-in Ubuntu backup tool, but rather a partition image made by eg. Clonezilla). One should assume that upgrade can **always** go wrong as this is a very complicated process and system configurations are very different, so before attempting upgrade you should always have a working backup you can return to.

Comment: hello alll..ive edited my original post and added screenshots to show the problem, does anyone have any further suggestions?...with thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to see your log files in `/var/log` but there's no way to be sure you'll find something (it's like looking for a pin in a haystack).
I'd personally try to look at `boot.log`, maybe `faillog` and `syslog` too...
There's also a `dist-upgrade` sub-directory you may wish to scout, in case something wrong happened during the upgrade.
If you find anything suspicious, edit your post with the new info.
When it comes to Ubuntu LTS upgrade, system Backups are NOT an option, I once learned it the hard way too...
Hope that'll help.

Comment: it might help, but is your post an actual answer, rather than a comment?